# C++ - Initialize array of pointers within a constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++11

I need an array of ***char* *** defined in as a class's attribute, and initialize it with a length inside the class's constructor. For example:

Foo.h:

```
class Foo{
    public:
        char * array[1]    // declare the array here, syntax unsure
        Foo(int length);
}
```

Foo.cpp:

```
Foo::Foo(int length){
    array[length]      // set the length of the array here, syntax unsure
}
```

Not sure about the syntax...I've only seen declaration of array of pointers with a length. I wonder how to declare it first and set/redeclare a new length later.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### How to use a dynamic array

Use an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
class Foo{
public:
    std::vector<char*> array;
    Foo(int length) : array(length) {}
}
```

In:

```
array(length)
```

you will construct a container with `length` default constructed `char*`. You can even use one of [the other](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) useful constructors. Specifically if you want to define `length` copies of the element `x` you can use:

```
array(length, x)
```

You can then, eventually, push them in with `push_back`/`emplace_back`.

### Few minor touches

If `char*` is semantically a string, then you should use `std::vector<std::string>`.

And if the class is minimal as you described it, then you can simply use:

```
using Foo = std::vector<std::string>;
```

The type alias won't create a new type, it will only create a new *type alias*.

Comment: note: `using` does not create a new type, whereas `class Foo` does (this is important for overloading, etc.)

Comment: For the `vector`, if I want to set the length inside the constructor (I need to calculate the length in it first), which function should I call? .resize(length) or .reserve(length)?

Comment: You should pass the length to the constructor.

Comment: @Fenwick What do you mean by "set the length"? See the documentation for [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) and [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize).

Comment: You should reword the *will reserve space* and *eventually, push them in* sentences. The `vector` constructors you're using don't just reserve space, but fill it with `length` elements.